# Index rebuild on SQL Server timeout after only 6 minutes. Timeout set to 60 minutes

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, indexing, timeout

I am executing the command

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [MyTable] REBUILD
```

I am using the EF method `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`

I am getting the following log messages from EF:

> Started transaction at 17-06-2021 04:43:07 +02:00
> -- Executing at 17-06-2021 04:43:07 +02:00
>
> Failed to commit transaction at 17-06-2021 04:49:09 +02:00 with error: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

As you can see I get a timeout after 6 minutes. I have set the timeout through EF to 60 minutes.

Other identical commands on other tables are running successfully for more than 30 minutes.

I am a bit puzzled about this part: "...or the server is not responding". What kind of response does EF expect?

The table contains 8 million rows and 10 indexes, so it is fair that it takes a bit of time. But strange to get a timeout after only 6 minutes.

- SQL Server 2017 (v14.0)
- Entity Framework 6.2.0

Comment: Index maintenance is typically something I'd see set up as a scheduled task on the database to run after hours, not executed from an application.

Comment: This is an application that performs data cleanup. It is running 24/7 but is rebuilding indexes "after hours". The performance of the cleanup is degrading a lot. I assume it is because of index defragmentation. I hope the rebuild of indexes every night will ensure performance.

Comment: I just added a bit of retry logic. Second try worked. Seems a bit strange. It is definitely not a "normal" timeout.

Comment: How are you setting the command timeout? Through [context.Database.CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.commandtimeout?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)? Or are you trying to do this through a connection string?

Comment: Database.CommandTimeout